# Spring Batch Azure Databricks example

Tags: spring-batch

I'm looking to implement the Spring Batch example which will read the data from Azure Databricks and write it into Postgres or any other systems.

How Spring Batch will connect to Azure Databricks and how data will be populated ?

I don't see Inbuilt ItemReader or ItemWriter is available yet? Does it plan ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to Azure Databricks via JDBC Connection and for one DB to another you can refer https://www.yawintutor.com/spring-boot-batch-read-from-database-and-write-to-database-example/.

Let me know , if this does help you